# Visual Studio 2019 error "The operation cannot be completed because BeginBuild has not yet been called."

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

I downloaded VS 2019 Community and every time I want to build or compile a program, I get the same message "The operation cannot be completed because BeginBuild has not yet been called." I use Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. I searched for the answer on the internet, but found nothing concrete. I tried to delete .vs folder and .suo file, but that didn't help either, .suo file comes back every time I try to build or compile a program so I can't get rid of it. I tried to reinstall VS 2019 multiple times but it didn't help. I get the same mistake at VS 2017. Does anyone know what the problem is?
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJI9f.png)

Comment: I had the same error message occur a single time after switching configurations in VS2019 Professional in Windows 10, but the next attempt succeeded.